# R - Create column and populate with data grouped from another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R called hues
It has a column called color which contains multiple colors as rows

I am trying to create a new column called colorez
Its values will be group names based on the values in color column

I have been unable to use ifelse correctly to solve the issue

```
hues$colorez <- ifelse(hues$"color == blue,red,purple,black, "primary")
            ifelse(hues$"color == yellow, "secondary")
            ifelse(hues$"color == pink,orange, "tertiary")
```

Below is what I would to create

```
color     colorez   
blue      primary
red       primary
yellow    secondary
purple    primary 
pink      tertiary
orange    tertiary
yellow    secondary
red       primary
black     primary
orange    tertiary
yellow    secondary
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier way would be to use a merge or a join. If you create a second data frame named *e.g.* `colors`, with columns `color` and `colorez` as shown in your example, then something like:

```
merge(hues, colors)
```

should work, assuming every `hue$color` is in `colors$color`.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to save some typing, you could also just do:

```
hues$colorez <- ifelse(hues$color %in% c("pink", "orange"), "tertiary",
                       ifelse(hues$color == "yellow", "secondary", "primary"))
```

Assuming that you have no other colors than those mentioned in your dataset of course.